# How to programmatically search and replace font color in Word using new Office-AddIns

Tags: office-js, office-addins

In MS WORD [VSTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/create-vsto-add-ins-for-office-by-using-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) you can find/replace text color as follows. Can we achieve the same in [new Office WORD-AddIn platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins) for [MS WORD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/word-add-ins-programming-overview). I'm using Office 2016.

```
    public bool ReplaceFont(Word.Range rng, string findWhat)
    {
       bool hasFound = false;
       rng.Find.ClearFormatting();
       rng.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
       rng.Find.Replacement.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlue;
       rng.Find.Text = findWhat;
       rng.Find.Replacement.Text = findWhat;
       rng.Find.Forward = true;
       rng.Find.Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop;

       //change this property to true as we want to replace format
       rng.Find.Format = true;

       hasFound = rng.Find.Execute(Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
                return hasFound;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Body.search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.body?view=office-js#search-searchtext--searchoptions-) method to find the ranges. Then iterate through the returned ranges to set the [Range.font.color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.font?view=office-js#color) property.